# Integrate Wikipedia category tree into website to use as a search function

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Could anyone please help. I'd like to be able to integrate the wikipedia category tree into my website. The purpose being to allow users of the website to assign individual category's as their 'interests' allowing other users with those same interests to be matched to them. Can anyone advise on how how i could get access to this category tree and how it could be integrated to achieve the functionality i require.

Comment: mmhh... Wikipedia category tree is an inextricable mess... I doubt it will be of any help... Anyway, you'll find data dumps here: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/

Comment: Thank you, have you any idea how i'd integrate this into the website?

Comment: Is your website running mediawiki?

Comment: Luckily the website has not been built yet. i am at the design stage, I'm looking for a inexpensive way of incorporating Wikipedia categories as searchable keywords. I also wont be developing it as a third party will do that.

Comment: This will have to be custom made from raw data. But again, do not bet on wikipedia category tree as a structured ontology. Its a bloody mess.

Comment: I have a static JSON file of the latest category graph. It's 250 Mb though, so contact me if you would like it. I'm not sure whether the hierarchy would work well for matching people's interests though.